# Need a WPF rendering tip

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, grid

I want to make a WPF Grid in which users can drag and drop controls from one cell to another and when the user is dragging I need to draw tips on the screen, like arrows. It's as if the tips were in ANOTHER LAYER in the screen. That is, they are not drawn IN the grid I mentioned.

The problem is: I don't know how to OVERLAP a "transparent" canvas over my Grid so that I can draw on it.

Do you experienced guys have some tip? THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are Adorners. You can read something about them here:
http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/wpf-overlays-or-better-adorner/

Comment: I appreciate your attention.
With adorners... can I draw wherever I want? I mean... my tips will not follow the mouse, they will appear over particular places.

Comment: It looks pretty much what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, an Adorner is like a layer above any control you choose. You can draw something or put any other controls in the adorner.

Answer (score 2):

[Heres an example with a listView control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ListViewDragDropManager.aspx?msg=3093847), pretty good.

[Heres a tut](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/wpf-overlays-or-better-adorner/) also decent.

[And even a section in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753340.aspx)

Comment: I appreciate your attention. I'll take a look at it.